# AngularJS: Transclusion creates new scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a new directive that uses transclusion and set the *scope* property to *false* (use parent scope). While it can access the data from the surrounding scope, the directive cannot update it.

Please the the example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lFjrq). When the first text box is modified, all bindings to *text* are updated, but when the transcluded text box is changed, only the reference in the same scope is modified. I my example I would like both textboxes to update all references to *text*.

Does transclusion create a new scope? Can this somehow be prevented?

Code from the example:

HTML:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tmpl.html">
       <ul> 
          <li>I want to stay here</li>
      </ul>
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <h2>{{text}}</h2>
      <input type="text" ng-model="text"></input>
       <mydirective>
           <li><input type="text" ng-model="text"></input></li>
           <li>{{text}}</li>
      </mydirective>    
  </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.text = 'Somestring'; 
})
.directive('mydirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: false, //do not create a new scope
        templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
        replace: false,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            element.find("ul").append(transclude());
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution myself. There is a way by using the `transclude(scope,fn)` function:

```
.directive('mydirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
        replace: false,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            transclude(scope,function(clone){
              $compile(clone)(scope).appendTo(element.find("ul"));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See the updated example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKLlm)

Answer (score 1):

Is is the way how transclude works… This can not be prevented…

The problem is that string is primitive value, so when you are changing it in child scope you are overriding it for a child scope, but not updating in parent scope.

There is a good article about scopes:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

To workaround this - you can create object to wrap text value:

```
$scope.data = {text: 'Something'};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bHpiF

Another way to workaround this is to use `$parent` from a child scope:

```
<mydirective>
     <li><input type="text" ng-model="$parent.text"></input></li>
     <li>{{$parent.text}}</li>
</mydirective>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/stlcn

It depends from case which one is better, but in general - I prefer first variant, avoiding primitive value under scope.